# Hide item from tabpanel

Tags: sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I have tabpanel

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    docked: 'bottom',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'One',
            id: 'one'
        },
        {
            title: 'Two',
            id: 'two'
         }
    ],
}
```

Can I hide first item in runtime somehow? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.getTabPanel().getTabBar().getComponent(0).hide();
```

Comment: it's simple like this: `Ext.getCmp('one').hide();` I saw a guy answered this (but then deleted it?!). It will work for sure, providing that you do not have conflicts in id definition

Comment: I don't put minus to him and I don't delete his answer. But his answer is not working (I try it before my question and after his comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `activate` listener to your first item and hide it when it activates.

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    docked: 'bottom',
    items: [
        {
            title: 'One',
            id: 'one',
            listeners: {
                activate: function() {
                    this.setHidden(true);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'Two',
            id: 'two'
         }
    ],
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are your trying to do...?

Comment: I want to hide first item, but in controller. I give solution already.
`this.getTabPanel().getTabBar().getComponent(0).hide();`